# Why are certain colours common English surnames, but not others?

Tags: etymology

Why are certain colours (e.g. Green, Black, White, Grey/Gray) common English surnames, but not others (e.g. Red, Yellow, Blue, Orange, Violet)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of surnames based on color?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45222/what-is-the-origin-of-surnames-based-on-color)

Comment: Please see this site's help pages for advice about how to ask good questions. A long-time moderator provides useful guidance about demonstrating your research [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043).

Comment: What would we give English people French names like orange and violet? Black and white sound more English. :)

Comment: @livresque: No, that question and its answers do not address why e.g. Red, Yellow, Blue, Orange, Violet are not common English surnames.

Comment: When Barney the Dinosaur and Avatar blue beings get here in real life, Purple and Blue might become more common surnames.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(word)), _orange_ only came into use as a colour name in the early 16th century, by which time English surnames were already established. The name derived from 'red-haired' was Russell, not Red or Orange.

Comment: There is already the House of Orange, the Dutch royal family.

Comment: @dakini - But that name is derived from a place in France, not the colour/fruit.